# $(document).ready not firing on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have the following code on my page:

`<script src="//path.to/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<script>
 /* Statements #1 - Defining some variables... */
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 /* Statements #2 - Doing some stuf... */
});
</script>
```

The above code runs well on Desktop and Android devices, but when running on iOS devices the Statement #2 doesn't work. I've checked the console, and there are no errors.

Just for testing, i've executed Statements #2 on console by copy/paste and it runs as expected - This don't work only automatically, with page loading complete.

PS.: I got the error on iOS devices - Testing with Safari on iPhone and debugging on a Windows 10 with Chrome remote using [iOS Webkit Proy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy)

Comment: share your both code of `/* Statements #1` and `/* Statements #2`

Comment: Are you certain that you are including the jquery plugin before the $(document).ready(...)?

Comment: @AlivetoDie - Statements #1 is only to declare some variables and Statements #2 is under `$(document).ready`, that isn't reached.

@Jordan - Yes, they are in that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem: Somewhere in my code, i had a function with a predetermined value, and only Safari thrown an error. So, i'm using this:

```
function myFunction(parameter) {
    /* Coll stuf here... */
}
```

Instead this:

```
function myFunction(parameter = undefined) {
    /* Broken code... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I found that it was because I had added 'async defer' to the end of the script include, which caused that function to be called before it was available - causing all subsequent javascript functions to fail. Not sure why this only happened in Safari and not Chrome/FF, but fun stuff.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js" async defer></script>

<script>
  $(document).on('ready', function() {
    $("#myForm").validate();
  });
</script>
```

Removing the 'async defer' part (that Google told me to add to increase page load speed) fixed the issue.